# mysql finding a popular value within results of another popular value query

Tags: mysql

I have a table full of stock and option positions (an "option position" is a combination of option expiration date and strike price). The columns:

```
userID - the person who owns the position
stock_symbol - the stock they own
call_expiration - expiration date for a call option they've sold against the stock
call_strike - strike price for the same call option
```

Users can have multiple stock positions for the same stock_symbol, and if they do then they may have different call options written against that same symbol. For example user 399 has 3 positions in AAPL, each with a different call option:

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
| user_id | stock_symbol | call_expiration | call_strike |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
|     399 | AAPL         | 2018-07-20      |         185 |
|     399 | AAPL         | 2018-07-20      |         190 |
|     399 | AAPL         | 2018-08-17      |         180 |
|     399 | X            | 2018-07-20      |          13 |
|     802 | AAPL         | 2018-07-20      |         190 |
|     802 | X            | 2019-01-18      |          14 |
|     802 | MU           | 2018-07-20      |          38 |
|     802 | MIC          | 2018-07-20      |        42.5 |
|     802 | AAPL         | 2018-07-20      |         190 |
|    1079 | MU           | 2018-08-17      |          39 |
|    1079 | X            | 2018-07-20      |          14 |
```

I want to know which stocks are most commonly held, but I want each user to have 1 vote (in the above data symbol X wins because 3 users have a position in it; AAPL has more positions but they are owned by only 2 users). So if the same user has multiple positions in the same stock_symbol then it only counts as 1 vote for that stock_symbol. If there is a tie in frequency then order alphabetically by symbol. Maybe there's an easier way but this works:

```
SELECT stock_symbol, COUNT(*) AS symbol_count FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT(user_id), stock_symbol FROM user_positions) AS temp
GROUP BY stock_symbol 
ORDER BY symbol_count DESC, stock_symbol ASC LIMIT 10;
```

Then I wanted to know which expiration date was the most common for each of the popular symbols. Here's how I'd find it for a hard-coded stock_symbol (AAPL). If there is a tie then the earliest expiration date wins:

```
SELECT call_expiration, COUNT(*) AS exp_count FROM positions
WHERE stock_symbol='AAPL' 
GROUP BY call_expiration 
ORDER BY exp_count DESC, call_expiration ASC;
```

Then, lastly, I'd like to know the most common strike_price for a given symbol and expiration date. Here's how I'd find it for a hard coded symbol and expiration date. If there is a tie then the lowest strike price wins:

```
SELECT call_strike, COUNT(*) AS strike_count FROM positions
WHERE stock_symbol='AAPL' AND call_expiration = '2018-07-20'
GROUP BY call_strike
ORDER BY strike_count DESC, call_strike ASC;
```

These work and I can put these calls into a php script and loop through the results of the first query (which generated the 10 most commonly held stock_symbols), but I'm wondering if there's a way to get mysql to do all of this for me.

The end goal is a table like this:

```
popular position #1: S1   E1   K1
popular position #2: S2   E2   K2
popular position #3: S3   E3   K3
```

Where:

```
S1 = the most commonly held stock_symbol when each user gets 1 vote
E1 = the most common expiration date across all positions for symbol S1 (if a user has multiple positions for that symbol then you can consider all of them)
K1 = the most common call_strike for all positions where the symbol and expiraiton date are fixed at S1 and E1. (if a user has multiple positions for that symbol then you can consider all of them)
```

I'm not sure if this is a bad idea or not but I thought of creating intermediate columns in my query that concat call_expiration+call_strike, or maybe all 3: symbol+expiration+strike; couldn't quite figure it out since in the first case (most popular symbols) I want users to only have 1 vote each, but in the next 2 queries (most popular expiration date and most popular strike price for that expiration date) it's okay to consider all of a user's positions, even if they have more than 1 for the same symbol. Maybe too much to do in a single query?

--- 6/24/18 Added sample data below ---

```
CREATE TABLE test_positions (
position_id int unsigned auto_increment,
user_id int unsigned,
stock_symbol varchar(10),
call_expiration date,
call_strike float,
primary key (position_id)
);

INSERT INTO test_positions 
 (user_id, stock_symbol, call_expiration, call_strike)
VALUES 
 (399,  'AAPL', '2018-07-20', 185),
 (399,  'AAPL', '2018-07-20', 190),
 (399,  'AAPL', '2018-08-17', 190),
 (399,  'AAPL', '2018-09-21', 180),
 (399,  'X',    '2018-07-20', 35),
 (802,  'X',    '2018-07-20', 35.5),
 (1079, 'X',    '2018-07-20', 35),
 (1079, 'X',    '2018-07-20', 35.5),
 (1079, 'AAPL', '2018-07-20', 190),
 (1079, 'AAPL', '2018-07-20', 185),
 (1079, 'MRK',  '2018-07-20', 62.5),
 (1079, 'MRK',  '2018-08-17', 60);
```

The desired query result with this data is:

```
+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
| stock_symbol | call_expiration | call_strike |
+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
| X            | 2018-07-20      |          35 |
| AAPL         | 2018-07-20      |         190 |
| MRK          | 2018-07-20      |        62.5 |
+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Because symbol X is held by 3 users. Even though AAPL has more positions, there are only 2 unique users that have positions in AAPL, so we're going to say X is more popular than AAPL.

Within the 4 positions for symbol X, the most common call_expiration is 2018-07-20, and if we look at all call_strikes where symbol is X and call_expiration is 2018-07-20, then it is a tie (2 have 35 and 2 have 35.5) so we want to choose the lower of the 2.

Within the 2 positions for MRK, it is a tie for call_expiration (1 each for the 2 dates) so we choose the earlier of the 2 (2018-07-20), and then if you look at all the positions for symbol MRK where call_expiration is 2018-07-20 the most common (well, only) call_strike is 62.50.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: sorry about that; just added sample data